# Closed form for integral with SinIntegral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, integral-transforms

MMA can't solve this integral:
$$\int_0^{\pi } \text{sinc}(x) \text{Si}(2 x) \, dx$$

The I use `FourierSinTransform` to find closed form,but I try a verify result is **not** the same.

```
 NIntegrate[Sinc[x] SinIntegral[2 x], {x, 0, Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
 (*2.4027105434028190639158433061486202249835206924230*)
 
 InverseFourierSinTransform[Integrate[Sinc[x] FourierSinTransform[SinIntegral[a x], a, s], {x, 0, Pi}][[1, 1, 1]], s, 2]
 (*1/12 (-\[Pi]^2 + 6 Log[2]^2 + 3 PolyLog[2, 1/4] + 6 \[Pi] SinIntegral[\[Pi]])*)

 N[%, 50]
 (*2.3936885520150980242996551820731613680710349076966*)
```

**What could be causing this discrepancy?**

Comment: I don't think your method works. I replaced SinIntegral with Sin to get a solvable  Integral. Then the symbolic and numeric values don't match the result using your transformation.`(CosIntegral[\[Pi]] - CosIntegral[3 \[Pi]] + Log[3])/2` vs `Sqrt[Pi/2]/2`

Comment: @Andreas. Yes it's works.See: `Integrate[Sinc[x] Sin[2 x], {x, 0, Pi}] - 
  InverseFourierSinTransform[
   Integrate[
     Sinc[x] FourierSinTransform[Sin[a x], a, s], {x, 0, Pi}][[1]], s,
    2] // Simplify`